# Is it possible to use Thurstmaster T3PA and Servo Base on PS4 without a wheel?

Tags: ps4, controllers, dirt-rally-2.0, f1-2019

I had the great luck to receive a Thurstmaster T3PA pedals as well as a Servo Base T300 for both Christmas and birthday, the 26th.

However, the racing wheel wasn't shifted yet because it comes from another country and my relatives couldn't get it in time. It is no big deal but I wanted to know if I could already use the T3PA pedals with my PS4, maybe connecting them to the Servo Base without a wheel. I couldn't find a way yet. I hoped to use the pedals while the gears and turning with the PS4 Dual Shock controller until the racing wheel arrives!

I have two games: *F1 2019* and *Rally Dirt 2.0*. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a 100% certain answer but maybe this will save some time to someone else. I didn't manage to find a way and I suspect there isn't a one. So I finally got to receive the racing wheel and stopped for looking to a solution. Happy racing to you :)